# Generic report format

Tags: design-patterns, format, report, reporting

My business application produces a report. Report usually consists of:

- a general header (left, right and center)
- a few paragraphs describing parameters used
- table header
- table data
- page footer
- page header
- report footer

There are at least 2 known requirements for the output format of the report:

- excel table (xls(x) file) - it would ignore some sections, but definitely would include *table header* and *table data*
- pdf

Now I would like my program to generate the report in a generic format. Then next module would produce the output in one of the known output formats, accepting extra optional parameters like font size and face. For today there are 2 output formats, but soon there could be more such to come, like html.

**In what format should I generate the report?**

I believe it will be a file or an equivalent memory structure. Together with a format I would expect a suggestion about tools and technologies to use. I will choose only an open source solution, but if you want to give other hints, it will be also valuable.

My programming environment is java, but if possible I would like to leave this choice open.

One of my ideas is to define something custom, mine, from scratch. I know how to do it, but first I would like to have a review of common ready-made solutions. That's where I ask for your help.

Comment: After receiving the first answer I realized that I am looking for a *report engine*. A question [Open Source Reporting Engines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126622/open-source-reporting-engines) is quite relevant. I am not sure, but maybe my question is not exact duplicate, as it asks about the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [jasperreports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library). It can generate plenty of formats. And you will get lots of community support.

Comment: A very interesting marriage of open source community and commercial application. I skated through the guide and it looks really promising and professional.